# @font-face alias issues on PC

Tags: css, font-face, antialiasing

Just started using this technique and am having strange results on the PC side. Virtually every browser I preview this site in on a PC makes the font look totally horsey. Example:

**On the Mac:**

http://dropbox.smallparade.com/howto-mac.png

**On a PC:**

http://dropbox.smallparade.com/howto-pc.png

Anyone have experience with this issue? Is there a resolution? Does it have anything to do with how the fonts were created? Appreciate any help I can get. I used the [**font-face generator**](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) over at fontsquirrel.com.

Comment: Um.. what's the typeface at hand?

Comment: Could you define the browser(s) you used on the PC? I suggest you try it IE7/8, Safari and Firefox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a [Hinting problem](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/TrueTypeHintingIntro.mspx).

When you generate your font-face kit (like in FontSquirrel), you need to specify Hinting on the Expert options.

Choose Expert, and under Rendering, select:

Apply Hinting - Improve Win rendering.

Comment: I'm trying FontSquirrel and they don't have the option you mentioned... they just have auto-hinting and font squirrel hinting... have they changed what it's called? which one should i use?

Comment: Choose the Expert option when uploading your font. Then, under Truetype Hinting, check TTFAutohint.

Answer (score 0):

probably you can specify font-size in px for example

```
font-size:11px/11px;
```

this might help you because i have faced same problem and i solved it like this only

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and just like Rinkalkumar I'd suggest specifying font-size.

But I've also found out that some fonts in some sizes simply render ugly.
So you may wanna try adjusting size few px +- just to check is this the issue.

Font face support isn't perfect yet, so if this proves to be an issue, you
may wanna try http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/   -  it involves javascript
but has proven to be great when you want fonts render consistently across browsers/platforms.

Answer (score 0):

[ttfautohint](http://www.freetype.org/ttfautohint/) will rebuild the font's hinting for you.